# iCarousel - disprar stop when an event

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icarousel

Hello I am working with the control iCarousel.

And knowing I'm not doing an item that came.

I want to call an alert when it stops showing which item has to the user.

Only Thanks

Comment: _"I'm not doing an item that came."_ - I hope so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure to understand fully your question, but i tried to answer :)
implement iCarouselDelegate and try this :

```
-(void)carouselDidEndDecelerating:(iCarousel *)carousel {
    NSLog(@"HERE : %d", carousel.currentItemIndex);
    //Popup with UIAlertView or do what you want to do :)
}
```

I hope i succeed to answer your question